# Golang Regex is supposed to recognize either or but not both

Tags: regex

How do I get my regex

```
\b([t][\W_]*?)+([ea][\W_]*?)+([s][\W_]*?)+([t][\W_]*?)*?\b
```

to hit "test", "tast" but not "teast" or "taest" with Golang?

And if someone also uses the letters in the regex more than once, something like "testt" or "teeeeeest", then the regex should recognize that too

https://regex101.com/r/ydvSR8/2

Comment: Why not this?`^t[ea]st$`

Comment: I also want it to recognize when someone uses the letters more often

Comment: I think you should be more explicit in your language. I don't know what "more often" means in this context. Perhaps you should offer a more complete sample set of values you want to "hit" and values you don't.

Comment: So, if someone now writes "testtttttt" or "teeeest", with yours it is no longer recognized, if someone writes "testt"

Comment: For the problem specified, there was a valid answer (in comment). *Then* you changed the question (via comment). Please specify your question precisely in tits final form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match either one or more `(e[\W_]*?)` or one or more `(a[\W_]*?)`:

```golang
\b(t[\W_]*?)+((?:e[\W_]*?)+|(?:a[\W_]*?)+)(s[\W_]*?)+(t[\W_]*?)*?\b
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ydvSR8/4). The `((?:e[\W_]*?)+|(?:a[\W_]*?)+)` pattern is a capturing group that matches

- `(?:e[\W_]*?)+` - one or more `e` and zero or more non-alphanumeric chars as few as possible
- `|` - or
- `(?:a[\W_]*?)+` - one or more `a` and zero or more non-alphanumeric chars as few as possible.